# Unlist column names and using it in facet_grid

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, paste

I have a long list of column names that I want to use it in the `facet_grid`. I would like to select some column names and put `+` as `facet_grid` function require.

I have tried this with `mtcars` but couldn't figure it out why `unlist` or `paste` are not working.

```
names=paste(unlist(names(mtcars)[c(1,3,5)]),sep='+')

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes("", hp)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.7, position=position_dodge(0.7)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(. ~ names,switch = 'both',labeller = label_both)
```

> Error in combine_vars(data, params$plot_env, cols, drop = params$drop)
>   :    At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a string inside `facet_grid`, but you have to provide the whole formula (including the tilde) as a string.

```
names <- paste(c(". ~ ", names(mtcars)[c(1,3,5)]), collapse='+')

ggplot(mtcars, aes("", hp)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.7, position=position_dodge(0.7)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(names, switch = 'both', labeller = label_both)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brian. Your solution is elegant!